# SQL, finding the minimum of the maximum of people living in housing sorted by city

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a relation `housing_complex` with the following columns:

- `city`
- `building_name`
- `inhabitants`

I want to create a query that finds the minimum of all the maximum inhabitants grouped by the city.

So far I can find a table of maximums with:

```
select max(inhabitants)
from housing_complex
group by city
```

How would I find the minimum of the output?

Answer (score 0):

you can use subquery

```sql
SELECT MIN(inhabitants)
FROM housing_complex 
WHERE inhabitants IN (
  SELECT MAX(inhabitants)
  FROM housing_complex 
  GROUP BY city
)
```

or in Common Table Expression (CTE)

```
WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT MAX(inhabitants) as m, city as c 
  FROM housing_complex 
  GROUP BY city
)

SELECT MIN(m), c
FROM tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would I find the minimum of the output?

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select max(inhabitants)
from housing_complex
group by city
order by max(inhabitants) asc
limit 1;
```